# If $|f(x)| \leq |x|^\alpha$ then $f$ is differentiable at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

In an exercise I'm asked to prove the following:

> Let $\alpha > 1$. Prove that if there exists a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that:
>
> $$\forall x \in \Bbb R, \ |f(x)| \leq |x|^\alpha$$
> then $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$

I think that we are supposed to use squeeze theorem or something like that to prove that the limit exists but the absolutes values on the condition are a little bit confusing to me to work with. How can I do this?

Comment: *Hint*: to prove that an expression tends to $0$, it is enough to prove its absolute value tends to $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, $f(0)=0$. And then, since$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x\right|=\left|\frac{f(x)}x\right|\leqslant|x|^{\alpha-1}.$$So, since $\alpha-1>0$, $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=0$.