# Differentiability in $0$ given $|f(x)| \leq g(x)^{p+1}$ for $g$ differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I am working on a question which states:

Given two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g$ is differentiable in $0$, $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and that for a $p>0: |f(x)| \leq g(x)^{p+1}$ for all $x$ in a neighbourhood around $0$. Is $f$ then differentiable in $0$?

I started by trying to find counter examples but I wasn't able to, so I set about proving that $f$ was differentiable in $0$. As $f(0)=0$ I know that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$.

At this point I get stuck and I'm not really sure how to continue. Can anyone give some hints? I imagine I need to get $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ smaller than something with $g(x)$ near zero but I don't really see how I can. Any help is appreciated. I have seen in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924277/if-fx-leq-x-alpha-then-f-is-differentiable-at-0) that it holds for $g(x)=x$, but in my case the function $g$ can be any differentiable function with $g(0)=0$.

Comment: Do you mean differentiability at $0$ instead of in $0$. One typically says `differentiability in $\nu$' for some variable $\nu$ if $\nu$ denotes a set, not a point.

Comment: The given inequality implies $f(x)/x$ is bounded in magnitude by $g(x)^{p+1}/x$, which is just $g(x)/x$ times $g(x)^p$. Now as $x\to0$, the first factor goes to $g’(0)$ and the second factor goes to $0^p=0$ (because if $g$ is differentiable at $0$ it is continuous there). Thus the product goes to $0$. So, by the squeeze theorem, $f(x)/x$ goes to $0$ as well. Thus not only is $f$ differentiable at $0$, its derivative is $0$ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac {g(x)} x \to g'(0)$ as $x \to 0$ so $g(x) \leq Cx$ for some finite constant $C$, for all $x$ in some interval around $0$. Now you can go back to the argument in the link.

[More precisely there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|x|<\delta$ implies $\frac {g(x)} x <2|g'(0)|$].